# How to have a unique selection across multiple CellTables

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

What is the simplest way to have multiple CellTables in a same page, so that selecting a row in one CellTable clears any selection in the other CellTables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is easier. Just create a unique SelectionModel, and use the `setSelectionModel` function to assign it to each of the CellTables.

Though this might seem obvious in retrospect, it took me a while to think of it.